# How to use multiple Git accounts with Windows Git Credentials Manager

Tags: windows, git

I have set up git config as follows:

```
Host ACCOUNT1
    HostName github.com
    Port 22
    User git-username1
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_2

Host ACCOUNT2
    HostName github.com
    Port 22
    User git-username2
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

When i `git push ACCOUNT1 staging` it fails and says "Permission denied...(PublicKey)"

This is because windows ALWAYS use `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa` no matter how i rearrange Hosts (ACCOUNTS1 and ACCOUNTS2 above)

UNTIL i rename `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_2` to `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa`, Then `git push ACCOUNT1 staging` works....

so every time I have to push to an account I have to make sure its Private Key is named EXACTLY "id_rsa"

Is anyone out there with the solution to ensure git on windows FOLLOW the git config set IdentityFile instead of falling to EXACTLY "id_rsa"?

Comment: You did setup the **ssh** part of the config but you still have to configure git's remote config to use different URLs. See man-page for `git push`.

Comment: @A.H. I have set the remote url as git@gihtub.com:username/repo .... that is why  it works when i change the naming of the Key to match id_rsa for both accounts1 and accounts2 remote URL...

Answer (score 4):

[VonC already provided the short answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70319491/1256452)  Here's the long one.

You're mixing up Git's *credentials* (used with http / https) and ssh's *public / private key based authentication*.  In particular, this stuff:

> ```
> Host ACCOUNT1
>     HostName github.com
>     Port 22
>     User git-username1
>     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_2
> ```

is a set of instructions for ssh, which you would put in your `.ssh/config` file.  Git simply runs ssh; ssh then does everything.

These instructions are slightly flawed.  In particular you want `User git`, not `User git-username1`.  This allows you to omit `git@` in your ssh request.  (If you include `git@`, the `User` line here is ignored, so the flaw becomes unimportant.)

To *make* ssh *use* these instructions, you must direct ssh to the pseudo0-host named `ACCOUNT1`:

```
ssh -Tv ACCOUNT1
```

from the command line, for instance, or `ssh -Tv git@ACCOUNT1`.  Ssh matches the string literal `ACCOUNT1` against the `Host` line, and then uses the remaining instructions—`HostName`, `Port`, `User`, and `IdentityFile`—when contacting the actual host.  The host ssh contacts is that listed in the `HostName` section, i.e., `github.com`.  The port used is 22 (ssh standard, so there's no need to list it).  The user name will be `git-username1` with the example, which is wrong, so you'd need `git@ACCOUNT1` as in the alternative to override the user name.

There's one further line missing: `IdentitiesOnly yes`.  This is not *required* but helps cut down on the number of keys your ssh will attempt when it contacts `github.com`.  With `IdentitiesOnly yes`, each key listed in the `IdentityFile` line(s)—you can have more than one—will be tried, in the order they are listed.  The order can matter since some servers may begin quietly *ignoring* keys after the first few.  (Imagine you're the gatekeeper, watching folks come up and try their keys in the lock at the door to the castle.  Someone—you can't see who as the light is too dim—comes up with a huge key ring with 1000 keys on it, and tries them one by one.  What do you think about this person?)

So, what I like to do is this:

```
Host gh1
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_github1

Host gh2
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_github2
```

and so on.  Then, when creating or updating the URL, I use:

```
git clone ssh://gh1/user/repo.git
```

or:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://gh2/user/repo.git
```

as appropriate.  To test each ssh setting, I use:

```
ssh -T gh1
```

or:

```
ssh -Tvvv gh2
```

as appropriate.  The number of `v`s here determines the amount of extra debug output from ssh: stuff at debug level 1 is emitted with one `v`, stuff at debug level 2 with 2 `v`s, and so on.  Debug level 1 suffices to watch the keys being tested.

Comment: Great Answer: after learning from you, all i had to do was change the `User ACCOUNT1` to `User git`. and `git remote set-url ACCOUNT1 ACCOUNT1:username/repo` as Per both of your answer with @VonC below

Answer (score 3):

> I have set the remote url as `git@gihtub.com:username/repo`.

Actually, if you want to use your `~/.ssh/config` entries, you need to set the remotes to:

```
git remote add ACCOUNT1 ACCOUNT1:username/repo
# or, if remote ACCOUNT1 already exists
git remote set-url ACCOUNT1 ACCOUNT1:username/repo
```

Only then a `git push ACCOUNT1 staging` light work.

Without a remote named `ACCOUNT1`, git push would use the URL `ACCOUNT1`, which is like `git@gihtub.com`, with `id_rsa_2`, but... *without* `username/repo`.
Pushing to `git@gihtub.com` alone will always be "permission denied".

And the `User` entry in `~/.ssh/config` should always be:

```
User git
```

Any other remote user would be "permission denied".

Comment: Thanks! Your Solution Works ONLY when i edit as follows: change my Config file `User ACCOUNT1` to `User git` . Maybe even removing that line would work

Comment: @CodeOneOnOne Good point. I have edited the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: @Wolf Thank you for your feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Wolf Again, thank you. There was a verb missing indeed!